# How open modal window on page load in wicket 1.5

Tags: java, wicket

I was using wicket 1.4.x for some time and solution found here worked pretty well:
[How to open ModalDialog on PageLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765790/how-to-open-modaldialog-on-pageload)
But when I moved to wicket 1.5 I simply don't know how make a modalwindow popup on page load.

A piece of code looks like this:

```
private PlainModalWindow tmpPassChange = new PlainModalWindow( "tmp_pass_change" );
tmpPassChange.add( new OpenWindowOnLoadBehavior() );
tmpPassChange.setInitialHeight( 418 );
tmpPassChange.setResizable( false );
tmpPassChange.setMaskType( ModalWindow.MaskType.SEMI_TRANSPARENT );
tmpPassChange.setPageCreator( new ModalWindow.PageCreator()
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public Page createPage()
  {
    return new TmpPassChange( u, tmpPassChange );
  }
} );
add( tmpPassChange );
```

To explain, I'm checking if page has a certain parameter. When there is one I search user with that parameter in datebase. When I have one I'd like to open PlainModalWindow, this window is class extending normal ModalWindow with a css removing style and that's it. The load behavior looks like this:

```
public class OpenWindowOnLoadBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void respond( AjaxRequestTarget target )
{
    ModalWindow window = (ModalWindow) getComponent();
    window.show( target );
}

public void renderHead( IHeaderResponse response )
{
    response.renderOnLoadJavaScript( getCallbackScript().toString() );
}
}
```

As I meanioned above, it worked in wicket 1.4 :(

Comment: Any JavaScript errors in console/debug window ?

Comment: nope console and ajax debug window is clear... thats odd cause it looks like the behavior is not even added to the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I couldn't find answer for this thing I made a workaround. Maybe it helps somebody. First add to HTML file link (display: none so no one will see it) :

```
<a style="display: none;" wicket:id="openPopup" id="openPopup"/>
```

Create an AjaxLink:

```
AjaxLink openPopup = new AjaxLink("openPopup") 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) 
    {
        tmpPassChange.show( target );
    }
};
add (openPopup);
```

And In renderHead method check your conditions for opening popup :

```
public void renderHead( IHeaderResponse response )
{
    String jQueryString = "";
    if ( u != null )
    {
        jQueryString += "jQuery('#openPopup').trigger('click');";
    }
    response.renderOnLoadJavaScript( jQueryString );
}
```

Hopefully it will help somebody, works for me :)

Comment: Of course I forgot to mention that you need jQueery for this solution