# wicket 6: calling javascript function after page load

Tags: javascript, wicket

This seems so simple, yet I cannot find an example of how to call javascript function from wicket, after the page is loaded (on page that extends WebPage). Can anyone give example on how to go that?

Comment: as noted in the question, the version of wicket is 6

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can have javascript do that for you

```
window.onload = function () {
// do stuff here
}
```

If you need parameters from your wicket page in the javascript function you can override renderHead and add the function there:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response)
{
    super.renderHead(response);
    String bar = "something";
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forScript("window.onload = function () {var foo='" + bar + "'}"));
    // or
    response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("functionToCall(" + bar + ");") ;
}
```

Comment: tried "response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("testAlert();")) ;" - works for me. thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Yet another way to do that is to create AjaxEventBehavior as follows and add it to your page.

```
AjaxEventBehavior event = new AjaxEventBehavior("onload") {
    @Override
    protected void onEvent(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        // do stuff here
        target.appendJavaScript("alert('onload');");
    }
}
add(event);
```

Comment: Can you add this to a component or does it have to be the page? Doesn't seem to fire when adding to a component...

Comment: appendJavaScript(), appends the mentioned function or the piece of the JS. When used in a Wicket function which is called repeatedly, the JS code gets executed multiple times and linearly increases.

Comment: This solution in Wicket 8 seems not to work anymore.

Comment: Is there alternative way for Wicket 8? @andpat